# codeigniter missing argument occured when hosted

Tags: php, codeigniter, arguments, hosting

If I open on localhost like this :
***localhost/example/product/category/1***
It will works, but
when I delete number 1 so the url like this :
***localhost/example/product/category***
It can be redirected on page where I had set, this is my code:

```
function category($id) {
  if(empty($id)) {
    redirect(base_url('index.php'));
  } else {
    $this->load->view('category'); 
  }
}
```

this code works perfect on **localhost**, but when I hosted it, and type to the url like this : ***www.example.com/product/category/***, this doesn't work and cause missing argument.

What should I do?
please someone help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code like this

```
function category($id="") {
  if(empty($id)) {
    redirect(base_url('index.php'));
  } else {
    $this->load->view('category'); 
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to attach some error this : **Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/disk2/602761/www/example.com/system/core/Exceptions.php:189)**

Comment: have echoed anything ?? i mean printed any value ?? like with echo, print_r(), print()??